# ReactJS select first option doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app with edit logic with select tag and options for continents and countries. In the continents it seems everything is alright but in countries I can't set a first option. First I must to select another country and then first option is available for set.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './editContact.module.css';
import { urls, methods } from '../constants';
import requester from '../services/requester';
import notificationsReceiver from '../services/notificationReceiver';

const EditContact = () => {
const id = window.location.pathname.slice(14);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
const [categories, setCategories] = useState('');
const [areas, setAreas] = useState('');
const [event, setEvent] = useState('');
const [continentId, setContinent] = useState('');
const [countryId, setCountry] = useState('');
const [continents, setContinents] = useState([]);
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);

const getContact = useCallback(async () => {
    const request = await requester(urls.contacts + '/' + id, methods.get);

    const response = await request.json();

    setName(response.name);
    setEmail(response.email);
    setAreas(response.areas);
    setCategories(response.categories);
    setDescription(response.description);
    setEvent(response.event);
    setPhone(response.phoneNumber);
    setContinent(response.continentId);
    setCountry(response.countryId);
}, [id]);

const sendToHome = () => {
    navigate(urls.mainPage);
};

const editContact = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await requester(urls.contacts + '/' + id, methods.put, {
        name,
        email,
        phone,
        description,
        areas,
        event,
        categories,
        continentId,
        countryId
    }
    )
        .then(() => {
            navigate(urls.mainPage);
            notificationsReceiver('Contact is edited successfully!');
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            alert(e.message);
        })
};

const getContinents = async () => {
    const request = await requester(urls.getContinents, methods.get);

    const response = await request.json();
    setContinents(response);
};

const getCountries = async () => {
    const request = await requester(urls.getCountries, methods.get);

    const response = await request.json();
    setCountries(response);
};

useEffect(() => {
    getContact();
    getContinents();
    getCountries();
}, [getContact]);

return (
    <form className={styles['edit-form']} onSubmit={editContact}>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Name</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)} value={name} />
        </div>
        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Continent</label>
        <select className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" title="continent" name="continent" onChange={e => setContinent(e.target.value)} value={continentId}>
            {continents.map(continent =>
                <option key={continent.continentId} value={continent.continentId}>{continent.continentName}</option>
            )}
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Countries</label>
        <select className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" title="country" name="country" onChange={e => setCountry(e.target.value)} value={countryId}>
            {countries.filter(x => x.placeIsContainedInId === continentId).map(country =>
                <option key={country.countryId} value={country.countryId}>{country.countryName}</option>
            )}
        </select>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">eMail</label>
            <input type="email" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Phone</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setPhone(e.target.value)} value={phone} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Description</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)} value={description} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Categories</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setCategories(e.target.value)} value={categories} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Areas</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setAreas(e.target.value)} value={areas} />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlInput1">Event</label>
            <input type="text" className="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" onChange={e => setEvent(e.target.value)} value={event} />
        </div>
        <button type='submit' className='btn btn-success mt-5' style={{ marginRight: 5 + 'px' }} name='edit'>Submit</button>
        <button className='btn btn-secondary mt-5' onClick={sendToHome}>Cancel</button>
    </form>
);
};

export default EditContact;
```

If someone knows how to resolve this problem, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Are you saying countries is empty until you first select a continent?

Comment: No countries is not empty, when I choose first option in countries nothing is happen, country is the same like before.